# API GET on button click?

Tags: javascript, api, get, frontend

is there a way to get data on button click then respond by filling a table of that data?

I've tried giving it an @click property using view that points to my router, but that didn't do anything, then i tried giving it a fucntion that points at the controller itself, but that didnt work either. I then tried adding an app.use middleware function that requests a link (app.use(request())) then send the body back but that didn't work either. when I do some of those, console gives me an error: require is not defined, or error: request is not defined.

the only thing i havn't tried would be adding a method to main.js on my client side, but I highly doubt thatd work.

for example, html button that says "get data" on click, execute a function in my controllers to get data, then when i get a response, display this data

Comment: So make an Ajax call....

Comment: What are you talking about? It sounds like you're trying to write server-side code in the browser.

Comment: @epascarello yeseseeee